# SAFE Module execution in a Smart Contract

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core

In NodeJS, executing with an EoA, the following transaction is to withdraw ERC20 from a SAFE to receiverWallet which is already a delegate with proper approval.

```
const tx = {
      from: this.wallet.address,
      to: this.chainsSettings[this.chainId].allowanceModuleAddress,
      data: contract.interface.encodeFunctionData('executeAllowanceTransfer', [
        erc20TransactionDto.wallet.address, // safe
        erc20TransactionDto.erc20Address.address, // token
        receiverWallet, // to
        ethers.utils.parseUnits(
          erc20TransactionDto.amount,
          erc20TransactionDto.erc20Address.decimals,
        ), // amount
        '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000', // paymentToken
        0, // payment
        receiverWallet, // delegate
        '0x', // signature
      ]),
      nonce: await this.getNonce(),
    }
```

We want to stop using an EoA and replace it with a Smart Contract for this we added the contract as delegate the same way as we do with an EoA, as the following:

```
safeAllowanceModule = IAllowanceModule("DEPLOYED_SAFE_MODULE_ADDRESS");
if (isSAFE) {
          safeAllowanceModule.executeAllowanceTransfer(
            address(_sender), // safe
            address(_token), // token
            address(this), // to
            totalAmount, // amount
            address(0), // paymentToken
            0, // payment
            address(this), // delegate
            new bytes(0) // signature
          );         
        } else {
          SafeERC20.safeTransferFrom(
            _token,
            _sender,
            address(this),
            totalAmount
          );
        }
```

This works with a ERC20 transferFrom but doesn't seem to work with the SAFE module, we keep receiving: "execution reverted: Allowance not set or insufficient" which is properly set to the contract address.

Is this something possible or is there anything wrong with our implementation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Where is that error thrown? It would be helpful if you could share the [Tenderly](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/explorer) link with the simulation of the transaction so it can be debugged.